# ag-grid pivot disable secondary group header row

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid enterprise edition with react.
When pivot mode is enabled, i want to disable secondary group header row.

Is there any property to disable secondary group header row in ag-grid.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this by setting the height to 0, see below for an example:

```
[pivotHeaderHeight]='0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivotHeaderHeight` on the top level of your gridOptions object. There are others to play on their api:

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/column-headers/